# Request timeout when pinging aws Linux instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins

So i m trying to install a jenkins server on the free instance provided by aws, so I can test things out, problem is that I can connect via ssh using putty to the public ip and my key, but when I try to access the jenkins portal using the public DNS address and the port a timeout is returned

Also if i try to ping the machine from my laptop it returns "Request time out" every time.

Also jenkins server seems to be running and active:

```
[ec2-user@ip-1235 ~]$ sudo systemctl status jenkins
● jenkins.service - LSB: Jenkins Automation Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-11-22 16:14:42 UTC; 7min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3693 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/jenkins.service
           └─3697 /etc/alternatives/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -DJENKINS_H...

Nov 22 16:14:42 ip-1234.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Start...
Nov 22 16:14:42 ip-1234.us-east-2.compute.internal jenkins[3693]: St...
Nov 22 16:14:42 ip-1234.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Start...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: Do you have a rule in your security group to allow ping and I assume port 8080 (Maybe 443?) for Jenkins

Comment: Hmm, so I have configured a TCP Custom rule, with ip 0.0.0.0/00 on port 8080, I ve read that this should give free access to virtually anyone

Comment: `ping` uses ICMP, not TCP. `ping` is not a good test of connectivity on AWS.

Comment: Yeah, read someting about ICMP, added it too, same 0.0.0.0, still dosen t work..

Comment: If you login to the instance, are you able to connect to the Jenkins server (eg `curl localhost:8080`)? If that is working, you can then investigate when external access is not working.

Comment: Yup, it works, it serves me a HTML DOM with a authentification required message, so I guess its aight